# Tablet evdev button event calibration

Tags: tablet, xinput

I have a tablet (Genius G-Pen 340 or UC-LOGIC Tablet WP4030U), it's detected and initialized as 'evdev tablet catchall'. Problem is that button event 1, simulated on axis 2, is triggered in very inconvenient way. 
Here is some lines from 'xinput test':

```
motion a[2]=6 
button press   1 
motion a[2]=0 
button release 1
```

As you can see, button 1 press happens when axis 2 (Z axis) has value more than 6 and released when its less or equal 0. But that level is about 1 cm above tablet surface, so these events triggered all the time and I can't move mouse cursor without causing button events.
Is there any way to calibrate event triggering threshold for axis?
Thank you.